# Java - How to make a JButton "Deselected"

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

When I make a JFrame, the thing in the top of the JFrame is automatically "selected".

Everything in the top of the JFrame/JDialog will be "selected" such as JButton, JTextField, ....How do I deselected (Using some code) it without using my mouse to click other area.

[image: This is the JDialog]

jButton1 mean the thing in the top of the JFrame(I use Snagit to capture it but the button "deselected" automatically)

Please help me. Thank

[image: The blue one jbutton means "selected"]

Comment: Can you provide something more specific than "The thing in the top of the JFrame", or provide some code to illustrate your question?

Comment: if you want to set focus on other components(say c) other than on the top of JFrame then you can use `c.requestFocus()` method.

Comment: "selected" mean clicked

Comment: You question still not clear..Do you want JButton1 to be selected by default .. or what??

Comment: What is that weird black think in the top? Is it censored?

Comment: @VishalK No I want all button deselected by default

Comment: @com.BOY the weird black thing is a JLabel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you show the JFrame using `setVisible(true)`. Set the focus request on JFrame using this line:

`frame.requestFocus()`

Answer (score 1):

In your main function call method `requestFocus` on the object you want to be selected after starting application.

Comment: No. I want all Jbutton and Jtextfield deselected